# Showing link into MatDialogConfig message box

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-material

I'm receiving String with hyperlinks inside.The String is:

`String` :
For accepting click here

```
<a href="link 1">click here</a> and <a href="link 2">click here</a>
```

But angular is showing it as plain text. Don't shows the links as hyperlinks.

My code is:

```
const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
              dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
              dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
              dialogConfig.data = {
                id: 1,
                description: 'Test Description',
                message: data['payload'].testMessage,
                buttonOk: 'Accept'
              };
              const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, dialogConfig);
              dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(
                data => {
                  if (typeof data == 'number') {
                    console.log('success');
                  }
                })
```

The result is the same text as the String - showing the  tag and  tag

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use Angular's `innerHTML` property binding like this, to show the hyperlinks:

```html
<div [innerHTML]="String"></div>
```

But keep in mind that with your implementation and code given, the `afterClosed` method probably will hold `undefined` as the value.